# Is it possible for a red black tree to have a node being black, node's parent being black, but the parent has no siblings?

Tags: red-black-tree

I'm reading through red black tree chapter from the book "introduction to algorithms" by Cormen. In that delete chapter, it basically says if both the node and node's parent are black, then the sibling of node's parent has to exist. The text is in page 327 first paragraph.

I don't get the logic for it, like how do we deduct something like that? Is that even true?

Though I did try to implement my own version of RB Tree and I couldn't produce a tree with a subtree like

```
      /
     R
    / 
   B
  / \
 B  ...
/
...
```

or

```
      /
     B
    / 
   B
  / \
 B  ...
/
...
```

Basically both node and parent are black but parent doesn't have sibling. Can't produce it so far

Answer (score 0):

The text is correct. The only time you can have a black node with no sibling is when the node in question is the tree root. The easy way to think of this is to draw out the B-tree equivalent, Moving red nodes up so they  are part of the same block as their parent black node. When you do this it becomes easy to see that a non-root black node with no sibling is going to produce an unbalanced tree.

In fact the two options for a non-root non-leaf black node are that either the sibling is black, or the sibling is red and has two black children (even if those two children are leaf nodes and simply represented by a null value in the implementation).

Answer (score 0):

SoronelHaetir is right. But there are 3 things to say about fixups of deletes:

1. When "sibling" is talked about, this is normally the sibling of the current Node. It is not usually parent's sibling. So if the current Node is the left child of the parent then the "sibling" is the right child of the parent.
2. You say "I don't get the logic for it, like how do we deduct something like that? Is that even true?". Yes it is. One of the rules is the total black Node count down every path is the same.
   So in a correct RB tree, for a given node, if the left child is black, then the right child is black (or it is red and it has 2 black children). For a correct RB Tree, you cannot have any node with an unbalanced count of black nodes down all paths. The count has to be the same in every path.
3. The other situation where you have unbalanced black tree count is where a leaf node has been deleted and it is black, and you are in the process of restoring the black tree count. Until it is restored (which can always be done), the tree is not a valid RB Tree.